# imagemagick command line convert script using Linux terminal

Tags: linux, graphics, command-line, resize, imagemagick

I create `PNG` image files with `GIMP` and want to make several icons from that `PNG` image of different, size and file names.

I wish to 'batch' convert with `ImageMagick` or something similar. And have the naming convention and size requirements read from a text file possibly because I also want to create another separate image using `GIMP` and have that re-sized multiple times with different file names on each also.

**Edit**

One image file needs to get converted into THIS:

```
  Icon.png  
  Icon@2x.png  
  Icon-72.png  
  Icon-72@2x.png
```

the file dimensions to be THIS:

```
  57x57  
  114x114  
  72x72  
  144x144  

$ convert image.png -resize 57x57 Icon.png  
$ convert image.png -resize 114x114 Icon@2x.png  
# ...etc
```

Comment: so what did you try and how did it work?

Comment: wishing to is a good start. The package mentioned by you has a convert utility which you could use for that purpose. You may want to get some clear ideas first how your naming conventions should look like, before you try to cast that into code. You're welcome.

Comment: Please show us the text file that controls how the process needs to work. Also, tell us if you are on Windows or Linux as the answer wil be different.

Comment: I have not created the text file.  It was an Idea I had to possibly make the automation go smooth.  I have to make icons of different size and naming: Default.png Default@2x.png, Default-568@2x.png Dimensions: 320x480,640x960,640x1136

Answer (score 0):

so if there's a text file storing the map "file name -> picture size" just in two columns, then you should be able to iterate through lines e.g. like this:

```
cat map.txt | while read line; do
  file=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  size=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')

  newfile=${file%.png}-new.png

  convert $file -resize $size $newfile
done
```

Comment: This looks close, would you mind taking a look at my original edited post?  the map is for the resulting names and size to be.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to guess what you mean, but suppose `params.txt` looks like this:

```
-resize 64x64
```

Then you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
params=$(cat params.txt)
for f in *.png
do
   newname=${f%.png}_new.png
   echo convert "$f" $params "${newname}"
done
```